# find the sum in the stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I found the average value for each student's subject. I need to calculate the sum of all student averages. for example, for Anna Math(0.5)+History(2.0)+Physics(3.3)=5.8
put in Map<String,Double> //name,sum
I want to find the smartest student

```
class Student3_1 {
private String name;
private Map<String, List<Integer>> marks;

public Student3_1(String name, Map<String, List<Integer>> marks) {
    this.name = name;
    this.marks = marks;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Map<String, List<Integer>> getMarks() {
    return marks;
}

public static Function<Map<String, List<Integer>>, Map<String, Double>> averageBySubject = marks -> 
    marks.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    entry -> entry.getKey(), 
    entry -> entry.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue).average().getAsDouble()));


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, List<Integer>> markAnn = new HashMap<>();
    markAnn.put("Physics", List.of(0, 0, 1));
    markAnn.put("Mathematics", List.of(0, 0, 0));
    markAnn.put("History", List.of(3, 3, 0));

    Map<String, List<Integer>> markKate = new HashMap<>();
    markKate.put("Physics", List.of(1, 2, 0));
    markKate.put("Mathematics", List.of(5, 0, 0));
    markKate.put("History", List.of(0, 2, 5));

    Map<String, List<Integer>> markBob = new HashMap<>();
    markBob.put("Physics", List.of(3, 2, 3));
    markBob.put("Mathematics", List.of(2, 2, 3));
    markBob.put("History", List.of(4, 4, 3));


    Student3_1[] students = {new Student3_1("Ann", markAnn),
    new Student3_1("Kate", markKate),
    new Student3_1("Bob", markBob)
    };
    Map<String, Map<String, Double>> averages = Arrays.stream(students)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student3_1::getName,
    student -> averageBySubject.apply(student.getMarks())));
    out.println(averages);


    Map<String, Double> studendSumAverages = averages.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                averages.entrySet().stream()
                        .map( x -> x.getValue().values().stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum())));
    out.println(studendSumAverages);
}
```

}

Comment: that is not a question for this site - it is more like asking for code ... as your previous couple or more questions. You will not learn much that way :-|

Comment: I'm not asking all the tasks. I select some items from the task that I can't solve

Comment: after explaining these examples, I solved a lot of examples. thank you all

Answer (score 1):

`Collectors.toMap` needs a merge function, so just replace

```java
Map<String, Double> studendSumAverages = averages.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                entry -> entry.getValue().values().stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum()));
```

By

```java
Map<String, Double> studendSumAverages = averages.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                entry -> entry.getValue().values().stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum(),
                Double::sum));
```

Then, to find the smarted student, you can do that

```java
String smartestOne = Collections.max(studendSumAverages.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
```

Comment: thanks. I search for the maximum through a cycle, you have a beautiful solution. I'll remember him. In YouTube, streams are in simple examples, it's difficult for me to understand how to combine all the methods of streaming. I have to solve such examples to combine different methods